# Foreign keys not recognised

Tags: subsonic

when generating an activerecord.cs from mysql using subsonic, some foreign keys are overlooked by the template. it acknowledges the table and columns, just not the relations.

i have checked all the basic things like made sure its the correct db, flushed tables, deleted classes etc.

the db is created using a dump. when i generate from this version everything works correctly. i then add some tables, which relate to existing ones. when i generate again, the new relations are missed by subsonic. the new tables have the same foreign key as existing tables.

ANY ideas will help me at this stage

thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved it. although my connection string was correct(used for table generation), the following line was incorrect(used for foreign key generation) in Settings.ttinclude:

```
const string DatabaseName = "db";
```